# How to close the window of an executable launched from CMD without using TASKILL [BATCH]

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have made a basic BAT script to download updates from Avast virus database and then apply them by running the downloaded file.

```
@ECHO OFF

set downloadFolder=C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\Avast_updates

set downloadUrl=https://install.avcdn.net/vps18/vpsupd.exe

bitsadmin /transfer myAvastUpdates /download /priority normal ^
  "%downloadUrl%" "%downloadFolder%\vpsupd.exe" 

start /min "Update..." "%downloadFolder%\vpsupd.exe"

exit
```

Also, I have created a Windows task to run BAT every x hours.

Everything works correctly, but I want to know if there is any way to automatically close the executable window after the update process is finished.

[image]

It occurred to me to use `TASKILL` after x seconds, but that doesn't assure me that the update process finished in x seconds, sometimes it can take longer and sometimes less, plus I don't want to use that command in an program security installer.

Then it occurred to me to send an "Enter" through `WshShell.SendKeys`:

```
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
cls
timeout /t 5 >nul
%SendKeys% "{ENTER}"

@end

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

But it did not work because that window does not close with "Enter" nor "ALT F4", it closes only if we click on "Done" or on the cross "x" to close the window (if it worked it would have the problem of setting the time again).

Is there a way to automatically close that window once the update process finishes?

Comment: `Taskkill /im notepad.exe` when used with a GUI program (as console programs do things differently) asks the notepad window to close.

Comment: see `vpsupd.exe /?` if there are any command-line parameters like `/silent`

Comment: @Mark, I don't know if I understood you correctly, I added that line and the Avast window did not close and the CMD did not finish either, both windows are still open and the CMD with the blinking cursor.

Comment: @Stephan, how do I do that?
If I do it like this: `start /WAIT  "Update..." "%downloadFolder%\vpsupd.exe /?"`, it gives an error Windows cannot find the file.

Comment: open a command prompt, `cd` to the location fo `vpsupd.exe` and just execute `vpsupd.exe /?` If that doesn't work, try `vpsupd.exe -?`

Comment: none of the ways yielded results

Comment: neither `vpsupd.exe /help`

Comment: an Avast window opens, performs the update process, and then ends with the "Done" window that I showed at the beginning of the thread. 
in CMD it shows nothing

Comment: ok, so it seems to run silently with `vpsupd.exe /silent` please try it.

Comment: The free Avast installer doesn't have a silent switch.[source](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=201898.msg1412451#msg1412451). But read the next entry too...

Comment: @Gerhard It seems to have worked, but by not showing anything, how do I know if it was updated correctly?
Doing tests I updated it many times, if I look at Avast it will tell me that it is updated.
I have to wait for a new update to be released to check for Avast.

Comment: @Gerhard, it worked! I just downloaded the update file and checked that Avast has been updated! Thank you very much!

Comment: Cool, so not all credit goes to me, @Stephan did mention the possible `/silent` switch, second comment on this thread `:)`

Comment: I already gave the point to @Stephan too, I don't know how the answers are marked as correct, I suppose I did well, I'm new here. : D

Comment: There are no answers yet - just comments. Want to self-answer?

Comment: That would be unfair, you found the solution, not me. Any of you create the answer and we vote it.:)

Comment: @Stephan, I suppose this one deserves an answer as the docs are pretty poor on the executable and the file does not present a help file. Then we clean up unrelated comments.

Comment: created an answer as "community wiki" to not get the points for this shared solution. (unfair to get the credits alone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Stephan and @Gerhard, the code to download and update Avast was like this:

```
@ECHO OFF

set "downloadFolder=%userprofile%\Downloads\avast_updates"
set "downloadUrl=https://install.avcdn.net/vps18/vpsupd.exe"
 bitsadmin /transfer myAvastUpdates /download /priority normal ^
 "%downloadUrl%" "%downloadFolder%\vpsupd.exe" 

"%downloadFolder%\vpsupd.exe" /silent

exit
```

Answer (score 8):

`vpsupd.exe` supports a `/silent` switch to suppress user interactions.

`start /min` isn't needed, as it just opens another `cmd` window, which in turn runs the executable. So just do:

```
vpsupd.exe /silent
```